# Entity Framework 4 exception not being thrown / caught

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am connecting to a MySQL database from Visual Studio 2010 using Net/Connector.

This is the entity framework 4 linq query:

```
        int timeThreshold = 5;
        DateTime cutoffTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-timeThreshold);

        try
        {
            using (var context = new myEntities())
            {

                var unprocessedMessages = from m in context.messages
                                          where m.createdDate < cutoffTime
                                          select m;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string exceptionString = e.InnerException.ToString();
        }
```

The Results view in the expanded unprocessedMessages displays an exception:

- base    {"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."}  System.Data.EntityException {System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException}

I am trying to see what the inner exception is. However, the catch block is never entered. What is happening here?

Comment: Select Debug -> Exceptions in VS, then tick the "Thrown" checkbox next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions." Then re-run the test.

Comment: Please update your existing question (edit link) instead of asking [a brand new question about the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514241/the-specified-type-member-datetime-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities).

Comment: Craig, this is a separate issue. "Entity Framework 4 exception not being thrown / caught" was specific to the exception not being caught.