# The specified type member 'DateTime' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, mysql-connector

I am using the latest development version of the connector - 6.3.3 beta to connect to a mysql database via the Entity Framework 4 in VS2010.

I have the following Linq statement which uses a TIMESTAMP column - createdDate  - in the query. Here is the code:

```
        int timeThreshold = 5;
        DateTimeOffset cutoffTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-timeThreshold);

        using (var context = new opusismEntities())
        {
            var unprocessedMessages = from m in context.messages
                                      where m.createdDate <= cutoffTime
                                      select m;
            try
            {
                foreach (var message in unprocessedMessages)
                {
                    int gfff = 5;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string exceptionString = e.InnerException.ToString();
            }

        }
```

The CLR is throwing the following exception:

"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to serialize date/time value.\r\n   at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object value, Int32 length)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.Execute()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)"

I’ve attempted to follow the advice from the following link:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52550

by declaring a DateTime instead of DateTimeOffset:

```
DateTime cutoffTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-timeThreshold);

...
var unprocessedMessages = from m in context.messages
                                      where m.createdDate.DateTime <= cutoffTime
                                      select m;
```

and use the format .createdDate.DateTime, but Entity Framework doesn’t like it and returns back an exception:

The specified type member 'DateTime' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

---

This was reported as a bug in previous versions of NET/Connector.

Hopefully the GA version 6.3.4 will fix this issue, but it still persists in 6.3.3 beta.

Comment: You try removing DateTime from m.createdDate.DateTime in your last query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4 exception not being thrown / caught](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505616/entity-framework-4-exception-not-being-thrown-caught)

Comment: Nix, my original query (first code block window) has the DateTime removed from m.createdDate.DateTime. I experimented adding it based upon a suggestion I saw in the mysql forums

Comment: Craig, this is a separate issue. "Entity Framework 4 exception not being thrown / caught" was specific the the exception not being caught. This is related to Linq and mysql Net/Connector

Answer (score 1):

Well this is LINQ to Entities issue..it does not allow you to use properties/methods like that in a query...not only for DateTime but for others too.

Get the value in another variable and use that variable in the query like

`DateTime dt=createdDate.DateTime;`

Or just remove DateTime...because it's value is the same...that should get rid of exception.But I am not sure what you are trying achieve though...

Comment: Misnomer, I don't think it's possible to get the value in another variable and use the variable in the query - the value has to be compared for each record. 

What I am trying to do:

Get all records from the messages table, whose createdDate (m.createdDate) value, (defined as a TIMESTAMP column in the MySql database), is not older than 5 minutes from the current time (cutoffTime)

Comment: what format is createdDate in ? is it like "2009-06-18 18:42:19.030" ?

Comment: You Could try using DateTime.Compare(m.createdDate, cutoffTime) < 0
...look here- 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx